# Vue CLI build to external host?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I have a Vue CLI application that I'm currently working on that uses code splitting for JS and CSS, and builds almost 1,000 JS/CSS files on running `npm run build`.

I am hosting this application on Google Cloud Run, where I pay per request.  While the cost is still not that significant, I was still looking to try and prevent the need for 500 requests for every page view. I had a thought, but I'm not sure it's possible...

What I was wondering was if I could have my webpack build generate the JS and CSS files into the `dist` folder, but reference those files in the `index.html` file with an external host, instead of assuming a relative path.  For instance, the file would exist at `dist/css/chunk-abc123.js` but in `index.html`, it would be something like `https://storage.google.../css/chunk-abc123.js`.

That way, in my CI pipeline, I can upload those files from the `dist` directory into Google Cloud Storage, and serve them up statically from there.

Does anyone know if this is possible?  If so, can you guide me in the right direction?

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputpublicpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`publicPath`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath) comes in rescue.

> The base URL your application bundle will be deployed at (known as
>   `baseUrl` before Vue CLI 3.3). This is the equivalent of webpack's
>   `output.publicPath`, but Vue CLI also needs this value for other
>   purposes, so you should **always use `publicPath` instead of modifying
>   webpack `output.publicPath`**.

```
// vue.config.js

module.exports = {
  ...
  publicPath: 'https://storage.google...'
  ...
}
```